# Is there a way to catch this unexpected value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
[(9, '['), (25, ']'), (442, '['), (460, ']'), (558, '['), (576, ']'), (608, ']')]
```

In this list of tuples I am trying to find key of "]" in the end.
If you take a closer look values goes like this;

```
[ => ] => [ => ] => [ => ] => [ => ]
```

But at last step it goes;

```
] => ]
```

I want to find key when this unexpected value appear.
How can I do that?

Comment: That's not a dictionary. It's a list of tuples

Comment: Corrected, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
from itertools import cycle

L = [(9, '['), (25, ']'), (442, '['), (460, ']'), (558, '['), (576, ']'), (608, ']')]
c = cycle(['[', ']'])

for t in L:
    if t[1] != next(c):
        print(t[0])
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical matching brackets exercise that is easily solved using the concept of a stack.

```
from collections import deque

brackets = {"[": "]"}
stack = deque()

for item in data:
    val, bracket = item
    if bracket in brackets:
        stack.append(bracket)
    else:
        try:
            openb = stack.pop()
        except IndexError:
            print(val)
        if brackets[openb] != bracket:
            print(val)

>> 608
```